# Conjunto usando matriz em c#

Tags: c#, matriz

Tenho a seguinte matriz:

```
a   d   k   m
s   j   e   r
t   c   f   p
```

Coloquei tal matriz em um array da seguinte forma:

```
char[,] matriz = new char[3,4];
matriz[0,0] = 'a';
matriz[0,1] = 'd';
matriz[0,2] = 'k';
matriz[0,3] = 'm';
matriz[1,0] = 's';
// E assim sucessivamente.
```

Eu gostaria de gerar todos os conjuntos possíveis baseados em tal matriz, levando em conta quantidade de colunas para determinar o tamanho do conjunto.
Logo no exemplo citado, seria possível criar **(3^4)** 81 conjuntos diferentes.

```
Ex.:
[1] "adkm"     [4] "adem"    [8] "adfm"      [11] "ajkm"
[2] "adkr"     [5] "ader"    [9] "adfr"      [12] "ajkr"
[3] "adkp"     [7] "adep"    [10] "adfp"     [13] "ajkp"
```

Qual seria a melhora maneira de varrer esse array e criar conjuntos baseados nas colunas?

```
int qtdColunas = 4;

char[] conjunto1 = new char[qtdColunas];
conjunto1[0] = 'a';
conjunto1[1] = 'd';
conjunto1[2] = 'k';
conjunto1[3] = 'm';

char[] conjunto2 = new char[qtdColunas];
conjunto1[0] = 'a';
conjunto1[1] = 'd';
conjunto1[2] = 'k';
conjunto1[3] = 'r';

char[] conjunto3 = new char[qtdColunas];
conjunto1[0] = 'a';
conjunto1[1] = 'd';
conjunto1[2] = 'k';
conjunto1[3] = 'p';
```

Tentei encontrar na web algo já pronto, mas não sei exatamente nomear o que estou fazendo.

Eu gostaria de uma solução limpa, rápida e com pouco consumo de memória.

A matriz dada na pergunta é apenas um exemplo, pois em meu código posso construir matrizes maiores. E é claro que não a preencho linha por linha como exemplifiquei.

Acredito ser apenas uma questão de lógica, mas boas práticas fazem muita diferença nessa hora. Por estar começando, eu não gostaria de cometer mais erros que o aceitável.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagino que isso resolva qualquer tamanho de matriz

```
    public static string[] TodosPossiveis(char[,] letras)
    {
        int linhas = letras.GetUpperBound(0) + 1;
        int colunas = letras.GetUpperBound(1) + 1;
        int max = (int)Math.Pow(linhas, colunas);
        string[] todos = new string[max];

        int[] posY = new int[colunas];

        int atual = 0;
        while(atual < max)
        {
            string nova = "";
            for(int i = 0; i < colunas; i++)
            {
                nova += letras[posY[i], i];
            }
            for(int i = colunas-1; i > -1; i--)
            {
                posY[i]++;
                if(posY[i] == linhas)
                {
                    posY[i] = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            todos[atual++] = nova;
        }

        return todos;
    }
```

Comment: Cara, se eu pudesse te dar + 2, eu te daria! Muito obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente. E usando tipos primitivos ficou da forma como eu queria.